# How do I get the content in javacript popups with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am using sweetalert2 on my website for creating popups. The sweetalert2 library adds DOM nodes to the page with JavaScript when a trigger is fired e.g. by clicking a button. The parent node of everything that is added is a div tag:

```
<div class="swal2-container">
   ...
</div>
```

In my Cypress test, I load the page and click the button that triggers the popup. However, the added DOM node (and its child nodes) are not found by Cypress:

```
it('Get content of popup', () => {
    cy.get("[id='popup_trigger_button']").click()
    cy.get("[class='swal2-container']", {timeout: 10000})
})
```

The test fails at the last row since the (added) node with the class "swal2-container" is not found on the page by Cypress. How can I get Cypress to find it?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until?

Comment: Thanks, but I only needed to add a timeout to the get() as described below.

Answer (score 2):

The class `swal2-container` is not the only class on the element you seek, so an exact match does not work.

Add a wildcard to the attribute match

```js
it('Get content of popup', () => {
  cy.get('[id="popup_trigger_button"]').click()
  cy.get('class*="swal2-container"]')
})
```

or use the more conventional (partial) dot selector

```js
it('Get content of popup', () => {
  cy.get('[id="popup_trigger_button"]').click()
  cy.get('.swal2-container')
})
```

---

This test runs against the SweetAlert2 demo page

```js
it('works with partial attribute selector', () => {
  cy.visit('https://sweetalert2.github.io/')
  cy.contains('button', 'Show success message').click()
  cy.get("[class*='swal2-container']")                    // passes
})
```

And this

```js
it('works with class selector', () => {
  cy.visit('https://sweetalert2.github.io/')
  cy.contains('button', 'Show success message').click()
  cy.get('.swal2-container')                              // passes
})
```

But his one fails because the class is incorrectly specified

```js
it('works with partial attribute selector', () => {
  cy.visit('https://sweetalert2.github.io/')
  cy.contains('button', 'Show success message').click()
  cy.get("[class='swal2-container']")                    // fails
})
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your response. I have tried a wild card and also getting other nodes where there is only one single class. The problem is that Cypress can't find those nodes at all. When the page first loads, the div tag with the "swal2-container" class does not exist in the DOM. When I click the trigger button, that node is added to the DOM, but Cypress can't see it. Is there a way to "refresh" Cypress's view of the DOM after the trigger button is clicked?

Comment: Nope, it does not matter that `div.swal2-container` does not exist before the button is clicked. Cypress has a retry that waits for it - unless your app takes more than 4 seconds to open the modal! In which case just add a timeout parameter. See above, tests that works against the demo page (which initially has no `div.swal2-container` element).

Comment: You are absolutely right. I added a timer and now it works. Thanks for your help, Steve!